# Are the headers between these 2 windows necessary?

Tags: framing, windows, window-frame

Found some water and old termite damage in some headers between an original 60's picture window and a vinyl replacement slider. Been talking to several contractors and one course of action was removing the headers entirely and mulling a picture window on top of a slider. Both would be new construction.

[image: Office Exterior Wall Framing]
The house was built in the late 60's. It's 2x4s on 16s. Stucco exterior.

Removing the headers would make the water proofing around the opening simpler. On the other hand I am concerned that they might help prevent the wall from shearing? The shorter wall on the left turns to form a solid corner. The taller side hits a tall opening after an interior wall.

Red indicates damaged headers. Yellow for the jack studs. Green for King Studs.

Is my concern about shearing on point? Do I need to pull in a structural engineer?

thanks!

Comment: Headers usually prevent the weight on top of a door/window from pressing down and also to provide structural support to the building.  Replacement with new is easy, moving can be harder.

Comment: Is the sloped top following the roof line? Is there plywood sheathing on the exterior?

Comment: @crip659 but assuming this is an end wall, i.e. there's a rafter above the wall, is a header strictly necessary, assuming the ridge beam is sufficiently supported?

Comment: There are a few"shoulds" that would need to be confirmed. As in the wall should be non bearing if the rafters are supported only at the top of another wall and at the bottom with yet again, another wall. There should not be a beam mid span supported of the rafters either below or "in-line" with the rafters to break the span into shorter runs.

Comment: Yes the sloped roof follows the roof line. Roof rafters are not supported on this wall. No plywood shear panels, house was built in mid 60's before that was required.